# how you hide uids in firebase in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

i want hide the uids from displaying on my display page, right now it displays -LrM8rlKq1-dSW6XRt0_({"color: 'blue"}), but i just want it to display ({"color: 'blue"}) without uid(-LrM8rlKq1-dSW6XRt0_) beside it  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WwWi.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WwWi.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import firebase from './firebase';
export default class App extends Component {
carDatabase = firebase.database().ref('car');
 state = { cars: {}, selectedId: '' }
 // Read
 componentDidMount() {
   this.carDatabase.on('value', cars => {
     const carsJSON = cars.val();
     this.setState({ cars: carsJSON === null ? {} : carsJSON });
   })
   // this.carDatabase.push({color: 'yellow'})
 }
 // Create
 create() {
   this.carDatabase.push({color: 'yellow'})  
   this.setState({selectedId: ''})
 }
 // Update
 update() {
  this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set({color: 'blue'}) 
  this.setState({selectedId: ''})
}
 // Delete
 deleteCar() {
    if(this.state.selectedId === '') {
      return;

    }

   this.carDatabase.child(this.state.selectedId).set(null)
  this.setState({selectedId: ''})
}
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
             <TextInput value={this.state.selectedId} style={styles.textInput}></TextInput>
               <Button title="create" onPress={() => this.create()}></Button> 
               <Button title="update" onPress={() => this.update()}></Button> 
               <Button title="delete" onPress={() => this.deleteCar()}></Button> 
               {
   Object.keys(this.state.cars).map( (carId, index) => (
         <Text style={{color: this.state.cars[carId].color}}>hi !</Text>
   )
}

       {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.cars, null, 2)}</Text> */}
     </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 textInput: {
   backgroundColor: 'green',
   height: 30,
   width: '100%'
 },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
 }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507653/how-do-i-change-firebase-output-to-text-with-native-react-from-what-i-have-now/58517392#58517392

Comment: You've created two post and this one with my response !

Comment: i tried this but it still prints out the -LrM8rlKq1-dSW6XRt0 part

Comment: nevermind i figured it out